# NUnit Test Adapter Discover Tests: Is it possible to ignore Projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I'm using the NUnit 2 Test Adapter extension for Visual Studio 2017.

Every time I build my solution the Test Adapter takes around three minutes to discover all tests, I'm guessing it's because there are more than 1100 Unit tests across multiple projects and even more projects without any tests.

I was wondering if there's a way to exclude projects from being checked for tests in the first place, since I usually only need to run the tests of one specific project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit can't avoid checking projects for tests, because the adapter is being told by VS to check alist of assemblies.

In the case of NUnit V2, that means checking every public class in the assembly and looking at all methods in each of them to determine whether this is a test assembly. The code that does this is in the V2 framework itself. The V2 adapter could, theoretically, check to see if the assembly contains a reference to the nunit V2 framework, but that's not likely to happen because V2 has not been developed actively for some time.

The best way around this is to convert your tests to use NUnit 3. The NUnit 3 engine, which is used by the NUnit 3 adapter, makes an initial check to determine whether the assembly references the NUnit framework. That's a lot faster, of course.

Of course, you are probably still using V2 for some good reason, so you'll have to weigh the pros and cons of the upgrade as it applies to your project.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Sadly I can't use the NUnit 3 Adapter because my team is still using the NUnit 2.6.3 framework.